# Get rows from matches with different teamId than playing user

Tags: sql

So what I am trying to do:

I want to get every row with the enemy champion (different teamId) for every match the summoner with the id 42999456 has played.

For example:

summonerId: 42999456
matchId: 2528256239

will return

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| matchId    | summonerId | championId | teamId | winner |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 2528256239 |   23364213 |        412 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   34928637 |        429 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   40909308 |          4 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   50717471 |        122 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   52439549 |         60 |    200 |      0 |
```

(note that I do not want to query for only 1 matchId, I want to query for all matches).

**The table looks like that:**

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| matchId    | summonerId | championId | teamId | winner |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 2528256239 |   23364213 |        412 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   23949601 |         32 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528256239 |   30032566 |        127 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528256239 |   34519064 |        236 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528256239 |   34928637 |        429 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   35157572 |         91 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528256239 |   40909308 |          4 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   42999456 |        201 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528256239 |   50717471 |        122 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528256239 |   52439549 |         60 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528415543 |   26264559 |        236 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528415543 |   30032566 |         79 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528415543 |   30066298 |        203 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528415543 |   30144484 |        201 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528415543 |   30420315 |         81 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528415543 |   35666995 |        238 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528415543 |   42999456 |        117 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528415543 |   55777006 |         75 |    100 |      1 |
| 2528415543 |   71020371 |        114 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528415543 |   75067455 |          1 |    200 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   20859869 |         41 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528508209 |   20926263 |         51 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   21489056 |         81 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528508209 |   30032566 |         62 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   31429371 |         19 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528508209 |   34198484 |        103 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   39520185 |         32 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   42954909 |        201 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528508209 |   42999456 |         40 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528508209 |   44449359 |        236 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528567430 |   22896699 |         64 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528567430 |   27716534 |         90 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528567430 |   30032566 |        157 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528567430 |   30161338 |         12 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528567430 |   33288363 |         30 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528567430 |   38554025 |         81 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528567430 |   40124474 |         62 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528567430 |   42999456 |         26 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528567430 |   61287205 |         92 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528567430 |   69117699 |        104 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528778889 |   19128606 |        102 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528778889 |   21226478 |         16 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528778889 |   24671894 |         74 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528778889 |   30032566 |         31 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528778889 |   42728001 |        157 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528778889 |   42999456 |        201 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528778889 |   43160768 |        236 |    200 |      1 |
| 2528778889 |   44918136 |         55 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528778889 |   52104644 |         51 |    100 |      0 |
| 2528778889 |   52420228 |         24 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529734554 |   19611148 |        412 |    100 |      1 |
| 2529734554 |   27427187 |        420 |    100 |      1 |
| 2529734554 |   27926072 |        117 |    200 |      0 |
| 2529734554 |   30032566 |         77 |    200 |      0 |
| 2529734554 |   33899765 |          4 |    200 |      0 |
| 2529734554 |   40093026 |        245 |    100 |      1 |
| 2529734554 |   42999456 |         40 |    200 |      0 |
| 2529734554 |   44385431 |         67 |    200 |      0 |
| 2529734554 |   49240203 |         81 |    100 |      1 |
| 2529734554 |   80637139 |         25 |    100 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   19648659 |         90 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   30032566 |        114 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   33120079 |         67 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   35688371 |         32 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529747312 |   35817488 |        106 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   36068030 |         41 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529747312 |   40406867 |        412 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529747312 |   42999456 |         44 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529747312 |   43212358 |        236 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529747312 |   52238049 |          8 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   20929372 |        105 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529802806 |   24507439 |        236 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529802806 |   24849750 |        238 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   28026768 |        117 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   30032566 |        223 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529802806 |   31689726 |         67 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   35685814 |         92 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   40621123 |        254 |    100 |      0 |
| 2529802806 |   42999456 |         40 |    200 |      1 |
| 2529802806 |   56868633 |         64 |    200 |      1 |
| 2530087947 |     108807 |         16 |    200 |      1 |
| 2530087947 |   19409641 |         84 |    100 |      0 |
| 2530087947 |   21422420 |         81 |    100 |      0 |
| 2530087947 |   23851356 |        112 |    200 |      1 |
| 2530087947 |   25847381 |         96 |    200 |      1 |
| 2530087947 |   27575895 |         11 |    200 |      1 |
| 2530087947 |   39058809 |         64 |    100 |      0 |
| 2530087947 |   39409025 |         61 |    100 |      0 |
| 2530087947 |   42999456 |         44 |    100 |      0 |
| 2530087947 |   54220113 |         41 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   19118675 |         40 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   20071645 |         42 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   29826523 |         11 |    100 |      0 |
| 2537795256 |   30032566 |         15 |    100 |      0 |
| 2537795256 |   37639463 |         31 |    100 |      0 |
| 2537795256 |   37741313 |        245 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   42999456 |        117 |    100 |      0 |
| 2537795256 |   46537422 |         80 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   71466951 |        238 |    200 |      1 |
| 2537795256 |   76797025 |         75 |    100 |      0 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of doing it is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT matchId, summonerId, championId, teamId, winner
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE matchId = 2528256239 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2
                  WHERE t2.summonerId = 42999456 AND
                        t1.matchId = t2.matchId AND 
                        t1.teamId = t2.teamId)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca212/2)

You can also use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.matchId, t1.summonerId, t1.championId, t1.teamId, t1.winner
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 
  ON t1.matchId = t2.matchId AND t1.teamId = t2.teamId AND t2.summonerId = 42999456
WHERE t1.matchId = 2528256239 AND t2.matchId IS NULL
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca212/4)